# How to Solved "get_transition_mixin.dart: Error: Too few positional arguments: 6 required, 5 given." Problem . When run IOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

> Error (Xcode):
> ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/get-4.6.5/lib/get_navigation/src/routes/get_transition_mixin.dart:608:57: Error: Too few positional arguments: 6 required, 5 given.

I clean cache. remove get package and add again.  in app i used GetTickerProviderStateMixin. for
animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration:800.milliseconds); that porpus.

Answer (score 0):

I use Flutter Master Version
Now I Come back to Flutter Stable version. And The Problem Solved.

Open terminal run
`flutter channel stable`
& run again `flutter upgrade`